# TableView doesn't update with ReloadData()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a tableView that contains two cell. The first cell contains a label and the second cell contains a DatePicker. The first cell uses the class:

```
import UIKit

class cell1: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
}
```

Another cell uses the class:

```
import UIKit

class cell2: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var outletPicker: UIDatePicker!

    @IBAction func actionPicker(sender: AnyObject) {
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name : "Main" , bundle:  nil)
        let view = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController
        view.lblString = String(outletPicker.date)
        view.tableView.reloadData()
        view.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

As you see in the DatePickerAction I want to change the label of first cell. In the mainClass("TableViewController class") I defined a string named lblString. And change it. MainClass code is like below.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    var lblString : String = "initialString"

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 30
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        if(indexPath.section == 0)
        {
           if(indexPath.row == 0)
           {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1") as! cell1
            cell.label1.text = lblString;
            return cell
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(indexPath.row == 0)
            {
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2") as! cell2
                return cell
            }
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if(indexPath.section == 0)
        {
           return 40
        }
        else
        {
            return 120
        }
    }
}
```

After MyDatePicker perform and `reloadData`, I can see `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function is running via breakPoint. But label of cell1 is still "initialString". How can I fix the problem?

[MyTableViewScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcxvc.png)

Comment: `let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name : "Main" , bundle:  nil)
let view = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController` This gives you a separate instance of the controller. This is not the same controller. What you can do is use a block to pass the change to the maincontroller

Answer (score 0):

In this method:

```
@IBAction func actionPicker(sender: AnyObject) {

    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name : "Main" , bundle:  nil)
    let view = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController
    view.lblString = String(outletPicker.date)
    view.tableView.reloadData()
    view.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

You're instantiating a new view controller, but you're not presenting it - it'll just get dealloced at the end of the method. Probably want you want is to pass a reference to the original view controller to that cell, or maybe use the delegate pattern to communicate from the cell back to the view controller, or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Line

```
    let view = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController
```

will instantiateViewcontroller instantiate new object. But it has no connection with the view controller you are presenting. Both are different that's why you are not getting that string there.

There are few solutions to this. Either you have to use Userdefaults to store that value and get back here or you can use protocols that trigger a method in tableview controller class.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with delegate method.
In your second tableViewCell, which contain a datePicker, create a protocol with pickDate function :

```
import UIKit

protocol pickDateProtocol {
func pickDate(cell:YourTableViewCell)
}

class cell2: UITableViewCell {

//outlets
@IBOutlet var outletPicker: UIDatePicker!
//variables
var delegate:pickDateProtocol?
var dateValue: String! = nil

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@IBAction func datePickerAction(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.pickDate(cell:self)
    dateValue = String(outletPicker.date)
}
}
```

And in your ViewController you will have:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController, pickDateProtocol {

var lblString : String = "initialString"

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) ->  Int {
    return 2
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,  heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 30
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    if(indexPath.section == 0) {
       if(indexPath.row == 0) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1")  as! cell1
        cell.label1.text = lblString;
        return cell
        }
    }else {
        if(indexPath.row == 1) {
     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2") as! cell2
     cell.delegate = self
            return cell
        }
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if(indexPath.section == 0) {
       return 40
    }else {
        return 120
    }
}
 // Mark: - Pick your date
 func pickDate(cell:cell2) {
    lblString = cell.dateValue
    tableView.reloadData()
 }
 }
```